# 2 questions about convergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I had a couple of questions about convergence and divergence:

1. Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ne^{-an^2}, a > 0$ converge? The main problem I have with this function is that it has an unknown variable a. Thankfully a>0, so I graphed it to see that the function always starts off increasing, then decreases. This seems to satisfy all the conditions for an integral test. Should I do that?
2. Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{(2n)!}{(5n)^n}$ converge? This one has $(-1)^n$ in it, so it is a changing series. I remember there was a way to express a fraction of factorials and exponents in a different way, like expanding the factorials and simplifying it, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first converges by the integral test:  $\int_1^\infty ne^{-an^2}=-1/(2a)e^{-a}\lt\infty $.

The second is alternating and decreasing, so converges by the Leibniz test.